# what does "timespan?" mean in c#?

Tags: c#, variables, nullable

what does the question mark mean at the end of the variable?

```
TimeSpan? begin = // bla bla bla
```

The coding language is c#

Comment: It´s a nullable type. It is not specific for TimeSpan but can be used on structs and primitive types. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy(v=vs.80).aspx#Y100

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) type. It means that value of begin can be null or a timespan

`TimeSpan?` and `Nullable<Timespan>` is same thing

Comment: Thank you! :) Concise answer.

Comment: of course, but it requires 8 more minutes to accept an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`TimeSpan?` means you're declaring a nullable type. A type which can support null values.